# Xpages HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception HTTP Code: 500

Tags: http, xpages, lotus

### Problem

I have an Xpage working properly on the test Domino server. 
On production Domino server it can not be opened, **Http 500** error displayed.

The two servers has different access control settings in the server document, but the signer of the application (production server) is listed in all programmability restrictions field except "Sign script libraries to run on behalf of someone else" field.

### Server log

> [25A4:0014-1604] 2012.11.07 14:06:30   HTTP JVM: SEVERE: CLFAD0141E: Error processing XPage request
>
> [25A4:0014-1604] 2012.11.07 14:06:30   HTTP JVM: SEVERE: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown
>   [25A4:0014-1604] 2012.11.07 14:06:30   HTTP JVM: SEVERE: CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /applications/application.nsf/xpage.xsp - HTTP Code: 500
>
> [25A4:0014-1604] 2012.11.07 14:06:30   HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception [/applications/application.nsf/xpage.xsp] CN=First Last/O=Company/C=Country Code

### Question

I have searched the net including IBM pages and forums for possible fix this error, but I have not found useable solution. Does anyone now how to fix this error?

Comment: What domino server versions you are running? Is Extension Library installed?

Comment: Recommendation: use try/catch in every of your SSJS codes, combined with OpenLog. Does not solve ALL Http:500 errors, but most of them.

Comment: Lotus Domino 8.5.3, Extension library is installed.

Comment: @Swen HasselBach: the error message from the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/ibm/xsp/extlib/component/dojo/form/UIDojoRadioButton.setSelectedValue(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the latest xpages_exc_*.log file in the data/IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder on the server for a more detailed explanation of the error.

If you don't have access to the file system on the server, then install and use the [XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Log%20File%20Reader) for easy access to the server log files.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. The lotus admin has left, but tomorrow I will check the content of the log file.

Comment: We have app which collects and attaches content of IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder as attachments. Highly recommended.

Comment: may be there is an issue with Java policy file who is different on both servers.

Comment: @Per Henrik Lausten: error message from the log:javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/ibm/xsp/extlib/component/dojo/form/UIDojoRadioButton.setSelectedValue(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Comment: Sounds like a bug in extlib. Are you using the same version of extlib on the two servers (I suspect not). Upgrade extlib to latest (or to match the test server). See this similar problem: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/defect.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=D7392AD70D948E468625793C0045E92C

Comment: Yes, we checked the two servers with the admin, and different versions are installed. On prod server there is an older one. Hopefully the upgrade will fix the problem, because the application works on the development server. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem earlier this week on a production 8.5.1 server (without extlib) and it was resolved by restarting the Domino server.

Answer (score 0):

Besides server security settings etc the issue can also be related to application specific settings. E. g. Fulltext index, database properties etc. It might be a good idea to compare these things too. 
Furthermore I also recommend using the Log Reader for easy access to the XPages log files...

Answer (score 0):

[Here I found a fix for the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925391/error-500-command-not-handled-exception-on-all-xpages/30111814#30111814?newreg=e8dc72f35a464a49b708405aee81b38c)

"
The resolution was discovered! We had added some Crystal Reports jar files to the C:\Lotus\Domino\jvm\lib\ext directory. It appears as if Domino and XPages did not like that. Instead, we had to put them in a directory external to Domino and then needed to reference those jar files in the "JavaUserClassesExt" line of the notes.ini.
After this was completed, Xpages worked!
"

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when I included the extlib.relational.library with the extlibx.library in the page generations property section of the Xpage property window. If I uncheck the relational library it works fine.