# Error 500: Command not handled exception on ALL XPages

Tags: xpages

We have an issue where no `XPages` work on our server any longer.  I am not aware of any server changes; however, I am sure something had to have been done.  I have no clue where to look.  We cannot get any XPages to work through any browser - tested with IE, Firefox, and Chrome.  We just get "`Error 500: Command Not Handled Exception`".  I just created a blank db and added an `XPage` with "`Hello World`" and built the project.  This error appears when I try to access that `xpage` through the browser.

```
04/28/2015 09:07:34 AM  HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in D:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

04/28/2015 09:07:34 AM  HTTP JVM: CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /test.nsf/testXpage.xsp - HTTP Code: 500. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in D:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

04/28/2015 09:07:34 AM  HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception [/test.nsf/testXpage.xsp]
```

`error-log-0.xml` shows those same errors:

```
CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown

CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /dev/samplepagersavestate.nsf/AllCars.xsp - HTTP Code: 500
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**Server version**: Windows 2012, 64 bit, Domino 9.0.1 FP2, HF590

Comment: Find the latest xpages_xxxx logfile in the data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT directory. It will probably show an stacktrace, that should help find out what is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xpages HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception HTTP Code: 500](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271653/xpages-http-web-server-command-not-handled-exception-http-code-500)

Comment: http://benpoole.com/weblog/201012151230

Answer (score 2):

Check the IBM_Technical_Support folder as Ferry suggested or install the [XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Log%20File%20Reader) also check if some other things has been done to the server recently. New version of extension library, Fixpack install.

Another thing is that I had a Windows 2012 installed server where I needed to apply 9.0.1 FP3 to before I got the xpage engine to run at all.

Comment: He might not be able to run XPages Log File Reader considering that "no XPages work on our server any longer." :-)

Answer (score 1):

The resolution was discovered! We had added some Crystal Reports jar files to the  C:\Lotus\Domino\jvm\lib\ext directory.  It appears as if Domino and XPages did not like that.  Instead, we had to put them in a directory external to Domino and then needed to reference those jar files in the "JavaUserClassesExt" line of the notes.ini.

After this was completed, Xpages worked!

Answer (score 0):

Is the user id signing/creating the XPage allowed to run XPages in the server document? It is the Sign agents or XPages to run on behalf of the invoker.

Howard

Comment: Yes, the user and the server has access to run XPages.

Comment: Update: Yesterday, I completely re-installed 9.0.1, then FP2, then Hotfix 590 (IF3).  After that was done, I modified the java.Policy file to include 2 additional lines under grant{ .  -  permission java.security.AllPermission; and permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";  The server was then rebooted and everything worked well.  I then learned that some runtime library jar files and a jdbc sql driver jar file were removed during the reinstall. They were to C:\Lotus\Dominojvm\lib\ext . A program doc rebooted the server overnight and now we can no longer see any XPages.

Answer (score 0):

plugins installed via update site uploaded by a person who is no longer in NAB?